Is it possible to orchestrate snowflake Notebook Job?
I have 3 note book created for different data operation . I want to orchestrate the notebook execution as per below flow
Execute Notebook 1
Execute Notebook2
Execute Notebook3
Based on certain flag in Notebook1, either Notebook2 or Notebook3 should be executed.
i found below example from the document using DAG
with DAG("mydag", schedule=timedelta(days=1), warehouse="my_warehouse_name") as dag:
    dag_task1 = DAGTask("LOAD_EXCEL_FILES_TASK", definition=f'''EXECUTE NOTEBOOK "{database_name}"."{schema_name}"."{env}_06_load_excel_files"()''', warehouse=warehouse_name)
    dag_task2 = DAGTask("LOAD_DAILY_CITY_METRICS", definition=f'''EXECUTE NOTEBOOK "{database_name}"."{schema_name}"."{env}_07_load_daily_city_metrics"()''', warehouse=warehouse_name)

    # Define the dependencies between the tasks
    dag_task1 >> dag_task2 # dag_task1 is a predecessor of dag_task2

# Create the DAG in Snowflake
dag_op.deploy(dag, mode="orreplace")

but when i execute with above example, it throwing syntax error
Unexpected '='

i also want to know if there any option run this notebook job parallel..
i mean, reducing number of task.
so how to achieve such scenario within Snowflake?

Have you tried simply using tasks and executing the appropriate notebook via each task?  You can then make the task dependencies.

Hi @MikeWalton so you mean there is no such option within notebook to orchestrate the process without using Stored procedure and then task

You don't need a stored procedure.  EXECUTE NOTEBOOK is a direct command, and you could create a task for each notebook and then make those tasks dependent on each other in a series.

@MikeWalton .. Ok .. do you have any sample code to showcase about this?

Sample code to show a task executing a command or sample

Sample code to show a task executing a command or sample code to show dependent tasks? In either case, there are plenty of examples in the documentation
